# Multiple MySQL connections from different threads

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading

I'm developing a multithread application where threads are created when someone connects to my socket. Each connection creates a new thread, and each thread make queries to a MySQL database using JDBC. I'm wondering if this multiple connections to the MySQL from my different threads could cause any problem in my application or negatively affects MySQL data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the contrary, you should always connect to a DB in a multithreaded fashion. Or really, a pooled fashion!

Consider the situation when your application becomes a worldwide hit and you get 100k hits a minute, then you will have a heck of a lot of threads - namely one per connection, which will break your application, your app-server and your DB... :-)

Instead you might implement a pool of DB connections from which your threads can borrow and return when done with. There are several good opensource projects to choose from for this, [C3PO](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/) and [Commons DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/) being just two of them.

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to be gained by having more threads than there are
actual number of cpu/hardware threads.  If anything, more threads
creates more overhead which will effectively slow your application 
down.

What threads do provide is relatively easy of way of doing more
of the same thing, but after a while it starts hitting a brick wall and one has to start thinking about other potential solutions.

If you want your application to be scalable, now is a good time to
start thinking about how you can scale-out your application, i.e.
a distributed solution where multiple systems share the load.

Instead of more threads on a single system, think in terms of 
work queues and  worker threads distributed across N systems.